# CSS works on somepages but not others?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having some issues on my website with some CSS I can't get to work.

For some reason on some pages the sticky navigation text remains visible while on others it doesn't. I'm not a developer but would appreciate any tips people might have.

This page it looks correct:
https://ecoheatcool.co.uk/underfloor-heating/

This page is incorrect and you can see as you scroll the links disappear. (White on white)
https://ecoheatcool.co.uk/

I would appreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how the text is white on white when you scroll on the homepage, you could add CSS to your custom styling:

```
.fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu>ul>li>a {
  color: rgb(1,62,72);
}
```

The color is pulled from the `background-color` of the navbar, but you could change it to any brand color.

Answer (score 0):

Well, upon scrolling, the navbar gets a few classes that give the links a white color. You can just remove these CSS selectors. In [this css file](https://ecoheatcool.co.uk/wp-content/cache/min/7/0055df27147e3fc580fd88adba4c8da1.css) remove the color attribute on line 3339 and on 3323. This should fix your problem.